How can I pass Data from swift to flutter?
In iOS, I have a model which has an attribute contains Data array:
var tmp = [Data]()
for imageURL in item.imageNames {
    let data = Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
    tmp.append(data)
}
item.imagesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tmp, requiringSecureCoding: true)

Then I wanna pass the item's data to flutter using this:
let dict = [String: Any]()
dict["id"] = item.id
dict["imagesData"] = item.imagesData

let itemData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionaries, requiringSecureCoding: true)

How can I receive the data in flutter and convert it to a flutter model?
I tried:
final Uint8List? result =
          await channel.invokeMethod('fetchItems');

But I don't know what to do next.
Any help will be appreciate.

https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon

Normally, we use plugins to write interactions between Flutter and the native end. On the native end, Flutter provides me with such a method:
public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "fetchItems":
         var tmp = [Data]()
        for imageURL in item.imageNames {
             let data = Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
             tmp.append(data)
        }
        item.imagesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tmp, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        result(item.imagesData)
    default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
}

On the Flutter end, we can call it like this:
static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');

Future<void> _getfetchItems() async {

  try {
    final var result = await platform.invokeMapMethod('fetchItems');
    print(result);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

}

    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/battery",
                                       binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())

Please remember, the name of the channel must be consistent with the channel name on the Flutter end, otherwise communication is not possible
